# Get SVN revision relative to head on CLI

Tags: svn

When I do a reverse merge (which often happens), I find it annoying to have to bring up the logs to find the exact revision number on which revision I would like to revert changes on. I know of the SVN keyword PREV, but sometimes it may be 2 or more revisions back. Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
svn merge -r HEAD-2:HEAD-3 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

I was wondering if anyone knows an easier way of doing this without having to look at the log?

Side note: The reason for having it more than 2 revisions back is that I use git svn (still learning to use) and occasionally, my dcommit will commit changes on all git branches as separate commits to the svn repo, despite only wanting to commit changes from a single git branch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way you can do this from command line without looking into `svn log`. One thing I can think about is that you can revert changes using graphical tool. TortoiseSVN on Windows as an example:

[image]